# How to determine the geom type of each layer of a ggplot2 object?

Tags: r, ggplot2, layer, proto, ggproto

As part of an effort to remove a specific geom from a plot I've already created (SO link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13407236/remove-a-layer-from-a-ggplot2-chart)), I'd like to dynamically determine the geom type of each layer of a ggplot2 object.

Assuming I don't know the order in which I added layers, is there a way to dynamically find layers with a specific geom? If I print out the layers like I do below I can see that the layers are stored in a list, but I can't seem to access the geom type.

```
library(ggplot2)
dat <- data.frame(x=1:3, y=1:3, ymin=0:2, ymax=2:4)
p <- ggplot(dat, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=ymin, ymax=ymax), alpha=0.3) + geom_line()
p$layers

[[1]]
mapping: ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax 
geom_ribbon: na.rm = FALSE, alpha = 0.3 
stat_identity:  
position_identity: (width = NULL, height = NULL)

[[2]]
geom_line:  
stat_identity:  
position_identity: (width = NULL, height = NULL)
```

I'm not familiar with proto objects and things I've tried from the proto [documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/proto/vignettes/proto.pdf) don't seem to work (e.g. `p$layers[[1]]$str()`).

---

Thanks to the answers below I was able to come up with a function that removes a layer dynamically:

```
remove_geom <- function(ggplot2_object, geom_type) {
  layers <- lapply(ggplot2_object$layers, function(x) if(x$geom$objname == geom_type) NULL else x)
  layers <- layers[!sapply(layers, is.null)]

  ggplot2_object$layers <- layers
  ggplot2_object
}
```

Comment: Just as an added convenience could you provide a small reproducible data set along with your code?

Comment: Whoops, copy-paste fail. Thanks, @Dason

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**ggplot 2.2 update:**
If what you want is a character string naming the geom type, you can use:

```
sapply(p$layers, function(x) class(x$geom)[1])
```

which yields the first class name for the geom object of each layer. In the OP's example:

```
[1] "GeomRibbon" "GeomLine"
```

The code in the answers above no longer give the results shown for version 2.2 The accepted answer yields two NULL values, and the other answer yields full `ggproto` objects.

Comment: Any ideas which version broke the code in my answer?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but version 2 from Dec 2015 introduced a bunch of major changes, so perhaps that? https://blog.rstudio.org/2015/12/21/ggplot2-2-0-0/

Comment: That was probably it.  Either way I added an edit to the top of my post redirecting to your answer since it seems to be up to date.

Comment: In light of the changes I'm now making this the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

**Edit: This answer is no longer current. It worked when the question was asked and presumably for quite some time after but for an answer that works with ggplot2 >= 2.2.0 see https://stackoverflow.com/a/43982598/1003565**

---

If we're just looking to get the geom name for each item this appears to be in the $geom$objname part of each layer.

```
p$layers[[1]]$geom$objname
#[1] "ribbon"
lapply(p$layers, function(x){x$geom$objname})
#[[1]]
#[1] "ribbon"
#
#[[2]]
#[1] "line"
```

As an added note - the reason you couldn't use the `p$layers[[1]]$str()` syntax is (probably) because you didn't explicitly load the proto package.  ggplot2 uses it internally but it imports it instead of using Depends.  Notice the difference:

```
> library(ggplot2)
> dat <- data.frame(x=1:3, y=1:3, ymin=0:2, ymax=2:4)
> p <- ggplot(dat, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=ymin, ymax=ymax), alpha=0.3) + geom_line()
> p$layers
[[1]]
mapping: ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax 
geom_ribbon: na.rm = FALSE, alpha = 0.3 
stat_identity:  
position_identity: (width = NULL, height = NULL)

[[2]]
geom_line:  
stat_identity:  
position_identity: (width = NULL, height = NULL)

> p$layers[[1]]$str()
Error: attempt to apply non-function
> library(proto)
> p$layers[[1]]$str()
proto object 
 $ geom_params:List of 2 
 $ mapping    :List of 2 
 $ stat_params: Named list() 
 $ stat       :proto object  
  ..parent: proto object  
 .. .. parent: proto object  
 $ inherit.aes: logi TRUE 
 $ geom       :proto object  
  ..parent: proto object  
 .. .. parent: proto object  
 $ position   :proto object  
  ..parent: proto object  
 .. .. parent: proto object  
 .. .. .. parent: proto object  
 $ subset     : NULL 
 $ data       : list() 
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "waiver" 
 $ show_guide : logi NA
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining why `$str()` was not available.

Comment: (five years later, this no longer works for the current ggplot version; posted a new answer)

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way of looking at proto objects. They are environments as I understand it, so using `ls` gives you the names (apparently even for items extracted from the parent environment which is the plot object, `p`.):

```
 ls(p$layers[[1]])
# [1] "data"        "geom"        "geom_params" "inherit.aes" "mapping"    
# [6] "position"    "show_guide"  "stat"        "stat_params" "subset" 

 p$layers[[1]][["geom"]]
#geom_ribbon: 

 sapply( p$layers, "[[", "geom")
#---------------
[[1]]
geom_ribbon: 

[[2]]
geom_line:
```

@Dason points out that you might have wanted a character vector as a result, so using sapply with "[[" again should satisfy that possible desire:

```
 sapply( sapply( p$layers, "[[", "geom"), "[[", 'objname')
#[1] "ribbon" "line"
```

The changes in ggproto design consisted of making the names reside an extra layer deeper inside the `class`-attributes:

```
 lapply( sapply( p$layers, "[[", "geom"), function(x) attributes(x) )
#----------------
[[1]]
[[1]]$class
[1] "GeomRibbon" "Geom"       "ggproto"   


[[2]]
[[2]]$class
[1] "GeomLine" "GeomPath" "Geom"     "ggproto" 

sapply( sapply( p$layers, "[[", "geom"), function(x) class(x)[[1]][1] )
[1] "GeomRibbon" "GeomLine"
```

Comment: Your sapply call still returns proto objects though which isn't ideal for working with.  If you grab the objname portion of what you return then you get a nice character string instead.

Comment: fixed that deficiency.