# unit test ( testthat ) graphs produced using ggplot

Tags: r, unit-testing, ggplot2, testthat

What is the best way to unit test (`testthat` R package) graphs produced using ggplot2?

I will be using fixed data so will be validating input table dt to ggplot2 using equal.

I am aware that:

- unit tests need to be done in isolation
- we need to validate that data is passed  correctly to ggplot?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to write a test for a ggplot plot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31038709/how-to-write-a-test-for-a-ggplot-plot)