# testing name argument in scale_continuous_fill()

Tags: r, ggplot2, testthat

**Question:** I am using the `testthat` package to test a `ggplot2` figure. I cannot find the location of the legend name (i.e., the `name` argument for `scale_fill_continuous()`). Where is `name` saved? (see my reproducible example at the end of the post for a concrete example).

**My searchers:** I have searched SO, but the other questions with the `[testthat]` and `[ggplot]` tags did not help (e.g., [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13457562/how-to-determine-the-geom-type-of-each-layer-of-a-ggplot2-object) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31038709/how-to-write-a-test-for-a-ggplot-plot)). I have also browsed through the [`ggplot2` unit tests](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/tree/master/tests/testthat) and could not find my answer.

**Reproducible example:** I am look for the location of `expression("Legend name"^2)` so that I can test and make sure it is correct.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(testthat)

# Create example data and plots
df <- data.frame(
    x = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 5, 6, 4), 
    y = c(1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1),
    z = rep(1:2, each = 4),
    group = rep(letters[1:2], each = 4))

my_plot <- 
    ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, group = group, fill = z )) +
    geom_polygon() +
    scale_fill_continuous(name = expression("Legend name"^2), 
                          low = "skyblue", high = "orange")

my_wrong_plot <- 
    ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, group = group, fill = z)) +
    geom_polygon() +
    scale_fill_continuous(name = expression("Wrong name"^2), 
                          low = "skyblue", high = "orange")

# Example tests that work
test_that("plot is drawn correctly", {
    expect_identical(
        deparse(my_plot$mapping$group),
        deparse(my_wrong_plot$mapping$group),
        info = 'The `group` aesthetic is incorrect.'
    )
    expect_identical(
        deparse(my_plot$mapping$fill),
        deparse(my_wrong_plot$mapping$fill),
        info = 'The `fill` aesthetic is incorrect.'
    )     
    expect_identical(
        class(my_plot$layers[[1]]$geom)[1],
        class(my_wrong_plot$layers[[1]]$geom)[1],
        info = 'There is no polygon layer.'
    )         
    expect_identical(
        layer_data(my_plot),
        layer_data(my_wrong_plot),
        info = "The `scale_fill_continuous()` data is incorrect."
    )         
})
```

Comment: There are missing `+` values in the ggplot commands before both `scale_fill_continuous` calls :)

Comment: @JonnyPhelps Thank you for catching the problem in my example.

Comment: I found the name argument at `my_plot$scales$scales[[1]]$name` / `my_wrong_plot$scales$scales[[1]]$name`.

Comment: @Z.Lin Thank you. It is there. Please write-up your comment as an answer and I will mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Short answer

Assuming your ggplot object is named `p`, and you've specified the `name` argument in your scale, it would be found in `p$scales$scales[[i]]$name` (where `i` corresponds to the scale's order).

## Long answer

Below is a long ramble about how I found it. Not necessary to answer the question, but it may help you the next time you want to look for something in ggplot.

**Starting point**: Often, it's useful to convert a ggplot object to a grob object, as the latter allows us to do all kinds of things we can't easily hack within ggplot (e.g. plot a geom at the edge of the plot area without getting cut off, colour different facet strips with different colours, manually facet width for each facet, add plot to another map as a custom annotation, etc.).

The ggplot2 package has a function `ggplotGrob`, which performs the conversion. This means that if we examine the steps along the way, we should be able to find a step that finds the scale title in the ggplot object, in order to convert it into a textGrob of some sort.

This in turn means that we are going to take the following single line of code, & go down successive layers until we figure out what's happening under the hood:

```
ggplotGrob(my_plot)
```

**Layer 1**: `ggplotGrob` itself is simply a wrapper for two functions, `ggplot_build` and `ggplot_gtable`.

```
> ggplotGrob
function (x) 
{
    ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(x))
}
```

From `?ggplot_build`:

> `ggplot_build` takes the plot object, and performs all steps necessary
>   to produce an object that can be rendered. This function outputs two
>   pieces: a list of data frames (one for each layer), and a panel
>   object, which contain all information about axis limits, breaks etc.

From `?ggplot_gtable`:

> This function builds all grobs necessary for displaying the plot, and
>   stores them in a special data structure called a `gtable()`. This
>   object is amenable to programmatic manipulation, should you want to
>   (e.g.) make the legend box 2 cm wide, or combine multiple plots into a
>   single display, preserving aspect ratios across the plots.

**Layer 2**: Both `ggplot_build` and `ggplot_gtable` simply return a generic `UseMethod("<function name>"` when entered into the console, and the actual functions in question are not exported from the ggplot2 package. You can nonetheless find them on GitHub ([link](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/4380cb97d55a91b6ef430d5b23327fab5c421b27/R/plot-build.r)), or access them anyway using the triple colon `:::`.

```
> ggplot2:::ggplot_build.ggplot
function (plot) 
{
    plot <- plot_clone(plot)
    # ... omitted for space
    layout <- create_layout(plot$facet, plot$coordinates)
    data <- layout$setup(layer_data, plot$data, plot$plot_env)
    # ... omitted for space
    structure(list(data = data, layout = layout, plot = plot), 
        class = "ggplot_built")
}

> ggplot2:::ggplot_gtable.ggplot_built
function (data) 
{
    plot <- data$plot
    layout <- data$layout
    data <- data$data
    theme <- plot_theme(plot)
    # ... omitted for space
    position <- theme$legend.position %||% "right"
    # ... omitted for space
    legend_box <- if (position != "none") {
        build_guides(plot$scales, plot$layers, plot$mapping, 
            position, theme, plot$guides, plot$labels)
    }
    # ... omitted for space
}
```

We see there is a code chunk in `ggplot2:::ggplot_gtable.ggplot_built` that appears to create a legend box:

```
    legend_box <- if (position != "none") {
        build_guides(plot$scales, plot$layers, plot$mapping, 
            position, theme, plot$guides, plot$labels)
    }
```

Let's test if that's actually the case:

```
g.build <- ggplot_build(my_plot)

legend.box <- ggplot2:::build_guides(
  g.build$plot$scales, 
  g.build$plot$layers, 
  g.build$plot$mapping, 
  "right", 
  ggplot2:::plot_theme(g.build$plot), 
  g.build$plot$guides, 
  g.build$plot$labels)

grid::grid.draw(legend.box)
```

[image: legend box]

And indeed it is. Let's zoom in to see what `ggplot2:::build_guides` does.

**Layer 3**: In `ggplot2:::build_guides`, we see that after some lines of code that handle the legend box's position & alignment, the guide definitions (`gdefs`) are generated by a function named `guides_train`:

```
> ggplot2:::build_guides
function (scales, layers, default_mapping, position, theme, guides, 
    labels) 
{
    # ... omitted for space
    gdefs <- guides_train(scales = scales, theme = theme, guides = guides, 
        labels = labels)
    # .. omitted for space
}
```

As before, we can plug in the appropriate value for each argument, & check what these guide definitions say:

```
gdefs <- ggplot2:::guides_train(
  scales = g.build$plot$scales, 
  theme = ggplot2:::plot_theme(g.build$plot),
  guides = g.build$plot$guides,
  labels = g.build$plot$labels
  )

> gdefs    
[[1]]
$title
expression("Legend name"^2)

$title.position
NULL
#... omitted for space
```

Yep, there's the scale name we expected: `expression("Legend name"^2)`. `ggplot2:::guides_train` (or some function inside it) has pulled it out of `g.build$plot$<something>` / `ggplot2:::plot_theme(g.build$plot)`, but we have to dig deeper to see which & how.

**Layer 4**: Within `ggplot2:::guides_train`, we find a line of code that takes the legend title from one of several possible places:

```
> guides_train
function (scales, theme, guides, labels) 
{
    gdefs <- list()
    for (scale in scales$scales) {
        for (output in scale$aesthetics) {
            guide <- guides[[output]] %||% scale$guide
            # ... omitted for space
            guide$title <- scale$make_title(guide$title %|W|% 
                scale$name %|W|% labels[[output]])
            # ... omitted for space
        }
    }
    gdefs
}
```

(`ggplot2:::%||%` and `ggplot2:::%|W|%` are un-exported functions from the package. They take in two values, returning the first value if it's defined / not waived, and the second otherwise.)

Annnnnnnnnnd we suddenly go from having too few places to look for a legend title to having too many. Here they are, in order of priority:

1. If `g.build$plot$guides[["fill"]]` is defined and `g.build$plot$guides[["fill"]]$title`'s value is not `waiver()`: `g.build$plot$guides[["fill"]]$title`;
2. Else, if `g.build$plot$scales$scales[[1]]$guide$title`'s value is not `waiver()`: `g.build$plot$scales$scales[[1]]$guide$title`;
3. Else, if `g.build$plot$scales$scales[[1]]$name`'s value is not `waiver()`: `g.build$plot$scales$scales[[1]]$name`;
4. Else: `g.build$plot$labels[["fill"]]`.

We also know from examining the code behind `ggplot2:::ggplot_build.ggplot` that `g.build$plot` is essentially the same as the originally inputted `my_plot`, so you can replace every instance of `g.build$plot` in the list above with `my_plot`.

**Side note**: This is the same priority list that comes into play if your ggplot object has some sort of identity crisis, and contain multiple legend titles defined for the same scale. Illustration below:

```
base.plot <- ggplot(df, 
         aes(x = x, y = y, group = group, fill = z )) +
  geom_polygon()

cowplot::plot_grid(
  # plot 1: title defined in guides() overrides titles defined in `scale_...`
  base.plot + ggtitle("1") +
    scale_fill_continuous(
      name = "scale",
      low = "skyblue", high = "orange",
      guide = guide_colorbar(title = "guide in scale")) +
    guides(fill = guide_colorbar(title = "guide")),
  # plot 2: title defined in scale_...'s guide overrides scale_...'s name
  base.plot + ggtitle("2") +
    scale_fill_continuous(
      name = "scale",
      low = "skyblue", high = "orange",
      guide = guide_colorbar(title = "guide in scale")),
  # plot 3: title defined in `scale_...'s name
  base.plot + ggtitle("3") +
    scale_fill_continuous(
      name = "scale",
      low = "skyblue", high = "orange"),
  # plot 4: with no title defined anywhere, defaults to variable name
  base.plot + ggtitle("4") +
    scale_fill_continuous(
      low = "skyblue", high = "orange"),
  nrow = 2
)
```

[image: multiple titles for the same scale]

**Summary**: Now that we've climbed back out of the rabbit hole, we know that depending on where you've defined the title for your legend, you can find it stored in the corresponding place within your ggplot object. Whether that title will actually be visible in the plot, however, depends on whether you've also defined another title with higher priority...

```
sample.plot <- ggplot(df, 
         aes(x = x, y = y, group = group, fill = z )) +
  geom_polygon() +
    scale_fill_continuous(
      name = "title3",
      guide = guide_colorbar(title = "title2")) +
    guides(fill = guide_colorbar(title = "title1"))

> sample.plot$guides[["fill"]]$title
[1] "title1"
> sample.plot$scales$scales[[1]]$guide$title
[1] "title2"
> sample.plot$scales$scales[[1]]$name
[1] "title3"
> sample.plot$labels[["fill"]]
[1] "z"
```