Is there a way to modify a quosure in a created ggplot2 object?
I created a ggplot2 object with the likert package. I have modified the fontface and the fontfamily of the labels using
p$layers[[2]]$aes_params$fontface = "bold"
p$layers[[2]]$aes_params$fontfamily = "Calibri"

The label that I want to modify is in:
p$layers[[2]]$mapping$label



is there a way to modify this to only show values with greater than 5%
reproducible example
options(digits=2)

require(likert)
data(pisaitems)

##### Item 24: Reading Attitudes
items24 <- pisaitems[,substr(names(pisaitems), 1,5) == 'ST24Q']
head(items24); ncol(items24)

names(items24) <- c(
            ST24Q01="I read only if I have to.",
            ST24Q02="Reading is one of my favorite hobbies.",
            ST24Q03="I like talking about books with other people.",
            ST24Q04="I find it hard to finish books.",
            ST24Q05="I feel happy if I receive a book as a present.",
            ST24Q06="For me, reading is a waste of time.",
            ST24Q07="I enjoy going to a bookstore or a library.",
            ST24Q08="I read only to get information that I need.",
            ST24Q09="I cannot sit still and read for more than a few minutes.",
            ST24Q10="I like to express my opinions about books I have read.",
            ST24Q11="I like to exchange books with my friends.")
str(items24)

l24 <- likert(items24)

lr <- plot(l24, 
     # Group the items alphabetically
     #group.order= group_names,
      # for sorting ascending negative answers
     # Plot the percentages for each response category
     plot.percents = TRUE,
     # Plot the total percentage for negative responses
     plot.percent.low = FALSE,
     # Plot the total percentage for positive responses
     plot.percent.high = FALSE,
     # Whether response categories should be centered
     # This is only helpful when there is a middle response
     # option such as "neutral" or "neither agree nor disagree"
     centered = FALSE,
     # change the ledgend position
     legend.position = 'bottom',
     # Wrap label text for item labels
     wrap=200,
     text.size = 6,
     text.color = 'white')

lr$layers[[2]]$mapping$label

I have tried
lr$layers[[2]]$mapping$label <- quo(rlang::as_quosure("ifelse(round(value) < 5, '', paste0(round(value), \"%\")", env = rlang::caller_env()))

lr$layers[[2]]$mapping$label <- quo(rlang::as_quosure("ifelse(round(value) < 5, '', paste0(round(value), \"%\")"), env = 0x000001eab3634ea0)

returns error
Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type
<quosure/formula>. Defaulting to continuous.
Error in `geom_text()`:
! Problem while computing aesthetics.     
i Error occurred in the 2nd layer.        
Caused by error in `compute_aesthetics()`:
! Aesthetics are not valid data columns.  
x The following aesthetics are invalid:
x `label = rlang::as_quosure(...)`
i Did you mistype the name of a data column or forget to add      
  `after_stat()`?


You can directly replace the existing quosure with a new one (although this may be missing some subtlety about the environment). Here's an example:
require(likert)
data(pisaitems)
library(plyr)
library(tidyverse)

##### Item 24: Reading Attitudes
items24 <- pisaitems[,substr(names(pisaitems), 1,5) == 'ST24Q']
#head(items24); ncol(items24)

names(items24) <- c(
            ST24Q01="I read only if I have to.",
            ST24Q02="Reading is one of my favorite hobbies.",
            ST24Q03="I like talking about books with other people.",
            ST24Q04="I find it hard to finish books.",
            ST24Q05="I feel happy if I receive a book as a present.",
            ST24Q06="For me, reading is a waste of time.",
            ST24Q07="I enjoy going to a bookstore or a library.",
            ST24Q08="I read only to get information that I need.",
            ST24Q09="I cannot sit still and read for more than a few minutes.",
            ST24Q10="I like to express my opinions about books I have read.",
            ST24Q11="I like to exchange books with my friends.")
#str(items24)

l24 <- likert(items24)

First, the original plot:
lr <- plot(l24, 
     # Group the items alphabetically
     #group.order= group_names,
      # for sorting ascending negative answers
     # Plot the percentages for each response category
     plot.percents = TRUE,
     # Plot the total percentage for negative responses
     plot.percent.low = FALSE,
     # Plot the total percentage for positive responses
     plot.percent.high = FALSE,
     # Whether response categories should be centered
     # This is only helpful when there is a middle response
     # option such as "neutral" or "neither agree nor disagree"
     centered = FALSE,
     # change the ledgend position
     legend.position = 'bottom',
     # Wrap label text for item labels
     wrap=200,
     text.size = 6,
     text.color = 'white')

lr


Now, replace it with a new quosure and note how this removes labels for bars less than 15% in length:
lr$layers[[2]]$mapping$label <- rlang::quo(ifelse(round(value) < 15, '', paste0(round(value), "%")))

lr


Another option would be to remove the original geom_text layer and replace it with a new one:
# Function to remove a ggplot layer
# Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46221054/496488
remove_geom <- function(ggplot2_object, geom_type) {
  # Delete layers that match the requested type.
  layers <- lapply(ggplot2_object$layers, function(x) {
    if (class(x$geom)[1] == geom_type) {
      NULL
    } else {
      x
    }
  })
  # Delete the unwanted layers.
  layers <- layers[!sapply(layers, is.null)]
  ggplot2_object$layers <- layers
  ggplot2_object
}

# Start with original plot and remove the text layer
lr.new = remove_geom(lr, "GeomText")

lr.new


# Now add a new text layer
lr.new +
  geom_text(aes(label=ifelse(value < 15, '', sprintf("%1.0f%%", value))), 
            position=position_stack(vjust=0.5), colour="white", size=5)



There are quo_get_env() and quo_set_env() functions that should be able to solve any issues with the environment.  Just get the old one, and set the new one using it.

If you wrap the expression in expr() it appears to work as expected, e.g.
options(digits=2)
#install.packages("likert")
library(likert)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
#> Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 4.3.2
#> Loading required package: xtable
library(plyr)
data(pisaitems)

##### Item 24: Reading Attitudes
items24 <- pisaitems[,substr(names(pisaitems), 1,5) == 'ST24Q']
head(items24); ncol(items24)
#>                 ST24Q01           ST24Q02           ST24Q03           ST24Q04
#> 68038          Disagree    Strongly agree    Strongly agree Strongly disagree
#> 68039             Agree Strongly disagree Strongly disagree    Strongly agree
#> 68040    Strongly agree Strongly disagree Strongly disagree             Agree
#> 68041          Disagree          Disagree             Agree Strongly disagree
#> 68042 Strongly disagree          Disagree Strongly disagree          Disagree
#> 68043             Agree Strongly disagree Strongly disagree             Agree
#>                 ST24Q05           ST24Q06           ST24Q07           ST24Q08
#> 68038    Strongly agree Strongly disagree             Agree          Disagree
#> 68039 Strongly disagree             Agree Strongly disagree             Agree
#> 68040 Strongly disagree    Strongly agree Strongly disagree             Agree
#> 68041          Disagree          Disagree             Agree Strongly disagree
#> 68042 Strongly disagree          Disagree          Disagree             Agree
#> 68043 Strongly disagree             Agree Strongly disagree             Agree
#>                 ST24Q09           ST24Q10           ST24Q11
#> 68038 Strongly disagree             Agree             Agree
#> 68039    Strongly agree Strongly disagree Strongly disagree
#> 68040          Disagree          Disagree Strongly disagree
#> 68041 Strongly disagree             Agree             Agree
#> 68042             Agree             Agree Strongly disagree
#> 68043    Strongly agree Strongly disagree Strongly disagree
#> [1] 11

names(items24) <- c(
  ST24Q01="I read only if I have to.",
  ST24Q02="Reading is one of my favorite hobbies.",
  ST24Q03="I like talking about books with other people.",
  ST24Q04="I find it hard to finish books.",
  ST24Q05="I feel happy if I receive a book as a present.",
  ST24Q06="For me, reading is a waste of time.",
  ST24Q07="I enjoy going to a bookstore or a library.",
  ST24Q08="I read only to get information that I need.",
  ST24Q09="I cannot sit still and read for more than a few minutes.",
  ST24Q10="I like to express my opinions about books I have read.",
  ST24Q11="I like to exchange books with my friends.")
str(items24)
#> 'data.frame':    66690 obs. of  11 variables:
#>  $ I read only if I have to.                               : Factor w/ 4 levels "Strongly disagree",..: 2 3 4 2 1 3 2 3 3 4 ...
#>  $ Reading is one of my favorite hobbies.                  : Factor w/ 4 levels "Strongly disagree",..: 4 1 1 2 2 1 2 1 3 1 ...
#>  $ I like talking about books with other people.           : Factor w/ 4 levels "Strongly disagree",..: 4 1 1 3 1 1 2 1 2 1 ...
#>  $ I find it hard to finish books.                         : Factor w/ 4 levels "Strongly disagree",..: 1 4 3 1 2 3 4 3 3 3 ...
#>  $ I feel happy if I receive a book as a present.          : Factor w/ 4 levels "Strongly disagree",..: 4 1 1 2 1 1 2 3 1 2 ...
#>  $ For me, reading is a waste of time.                     : Factor w/ 4 levels "Strongly disagree",..: 1 3 4 2 2 3 2 2 3 4 ...
#>  $ I enjoy going to a bookstore or a library.              : Factor w/ 4 levels "Strongly disagree",..: 3 1 1 3 2 1 2 1 2 1 ...
#>  $ I read only to get information that I need.             : Factor w/ 4 levels "Strongly disagree",..: 2 3 3 1 3 3 4 2 3 4 ...
#>  $ I cannot sit still and read for more than a few minutes.: Factor w/ 4 levels "Strongly disagree",..: 1 4 2 1 3 4 3 1 3 4 ...
#>  $ I like to express my opinions about books I have read.  : Factor w/ 4 levels "Strongly disagree",..: 3 1 2 3 3 1 3 2 3 3 ...
#>  $ I like to exchange books with my friends.               : Factor w/ 4 levels "Strongly disagree",..: 3 1 1 3 1 1 2 3 3 1 ...

l24 <- likert(items24)

lr <- plot(l24, 
           # Group the items alphabetically
           #group.order= group_names,
           # for sorting ascending negative answers
           # Plot the percentages for each response category
           plot.percents = TRUE,
           # Plot the total percentage for negative responses
           plot.percent.low = FALSE,
           # Plot the total percentage for positive responses
           plot.percent.high = FALSE,
           # Whether response categories should be centered
           # This is only helpful when there is a middle response
           # option such as "neutral" or "neither agree nor disagree"
           centered = FALSE,
           # change the ledgend position
           legend.position = 'bottom',
           # Wrap label text for item labels
           wrap=200,
           text.size = 6,
           text.color = 'white')

lr$layers[[2]]$mapping$label <- rlang::as_quosure(rlang::expr(ifelse(round(value) < 5, '', paste0(round(value), "%"))), env = rlang::caller_env())
lr



# <10 instead of <5
lr$layers[[2]]$mapping$label <- rlang::as_quosure(rlang::expr(ifelse(round(value) < 10, '', paste0(round(value), "%"))), env = rlang::caller_env())
lr


Created on 2024-04-12 with reprex v2.1.0
Does that solve your problem?
